# Create staticmethod from an existing method outside of the class? ("unbound method" error)

Tags: python

How can you make a class method static after the class is defined?  In other words, why does the third case fail?

```
>>> class b:
...  @staticmethod
...  def foo():
...   pass
...
>>> b.foo()
>>> class c:
...  def foo():
...   pass
...  foo = staticmethod( foo )
...
>>> c.foo()
>>> class d:
...  def foo():
...   pass
...
>>> d.foo = staticmethod( d.foo )
>>> d.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method foo() must be called with d instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the class is defined, `foo` is an unbound method object (a wrapper that ties the function to the class), not a function. The wrapper's going to try to pass an instance of the class (`self`) to the function as the first argument and so it complains that you haven't given it one.

`staticmethod()` should really be used only with functions. While the class is still being defined (as in your `b` and `c`) `foo()` is still a function, as the method wrapper is applied when the class definition is complete.

It's possible to extract the function from the unbound method object, apply `staticmethod()`, and assign it back to the class.

```
class d(object):
    def foo():
       pass

d.foo = staticmethod(d.foo.im_func)
```

In Python 3, there are no unbound instance methods (methods stored on classes are plain functions). So your original code would actually work fine on Python 3.

A way that works on both Python 2 and Python 3 is:

```
d.foo = staticmethod(d.__dict__['foo'])
```

(It also avoids creating and discarding the method wrapper.)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `d.foo.im_func` ?

Comment: Well, you need to mark them with `staticmethod` in order to call them equivalently on instances, not just the class itself. `d.foo()` works with or without `staticmethod` wrapping, but `d().foo()` would explode (it would try to pass `self` which `foo` doesn't accept). Sure, there is no instance-related feature that would necessitate calling them on an instance, but for DRY, methods that reference the static method can and should call it as `self.foo()` instead of explicitly naming the class.

Comment: Also, using `im_func` means creating and then discarding an unbound method on Py2, and it's not portable if the code must run on both Py2 and Py3 (the latter not having an `im_func` attribute even on bound methods, let alone raw functions). You can portably bypass the creation of unbound methods entirely by accessing the class dictionary directly, which bypasses the descriptor protocol, making it slightly more efficient, and fully portable: `d.foo = staticmethod(d.__dict__['foo'])`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the comments. I've edited my answer. I imagine a lot of my nearly-five-year-old answers could be likewise improved...

Answer (score 5):

You must pass the function, not the unbound method.

```
>>> class d:
...   def foo():
...     pass
... 
>>> d.foo = staticmethod(d.foo.im_func)
>>> d.foo()
```